# Unit test client side JavaScript with Jest in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to unit test a plain old JavaScript client side code library (not using HTML-DOM or stuff like that) with Node and Jest.

If start up Node and `.load foo.js`, it loads the code I wish to test. And I can call the functions and all that.

But unit tests are nice to have and so I decided to `npm init` some package and to use Jest as unit test framework.

How do I load my file so the test code in `foo.test.js` can do the same calls I can do from the Node REPL?

`require('./foo')` is not working because it is not a CommonJS module. Likewise answers which hinted to `require('fs')`, `require('vm')` and stuff did not work in my case. Since it is a code library for the client side (browser), I do not want to make it a module. It is just a bit of script.

If I paste the code-under-test into the `foo.test.js`, it works.
So, my conclusion is that I will have to append the test code to the testee code as a file operation. Is there a better way?

```
//const cu = require('./foo');

// this is the content of foo.js, pasted into the foo.test.js.
var std = {
  nothingP : function (x) { return x === undefined || x == null; }
};
// true foo.test.js content
test('std.nothingP', () => {
  expect(std.nothingP(null)).toBe(true);
  expect(std.nothingP(undefined)).toBe(true);
  expect(std.nothingP(42)).toBe(false);
  expect(std.nothingP("Hello World")).toBe(false);
  expect(std.nothingP({})).toBe(false);
  expect(std.nothingP([])).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: So `./foo` is not a module?

Comment: @Konrad Correct! And I also tried `const cu = require('./foo.js');`, btw. Unless of course you understand under module something else. There is a npm init package.json and the source file. But the source file is not a module and the package is just to get jest orchestrated. (so I can type `npm test`)

Comment: Doesn't `import './foo';` work?

Comment: I assumed import looks for `exports` in the source file. So I did not consider it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't

Comment: @konrad I just updated node to latest stable but... "Error: You need to run with a version of node that supports ES Modules in the VM API." With the import version.

Comment: Could you expand on `fs` answers not working in your case? `eval(require("node:fs").readFileSync("./foo.js", "utf8"));` at the top of the test file seems perfectly happy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that (without the second argument) and it did not work. also the vm and run in this context version. And Bard either fantasized or knew about a function which my tools claimed did not exist...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Also your edits change the writing style - nothing wrong with my writing style, I think and nothing wrong to show it was not a robot who wrote the question....

Answer (score 0):

I created a `Makefile` to construct the `foo.test.js` from the source file `foo.js` and the file with the tests cases `foo-tests.js`, using the unix cat command.

Now I can `make` and then `npm test`.

```
SOURCES = ../foo.js ./foo-tests.js
OUT = ./foo.test.js

$(OUT):$(SOURCES) Makefile
    truncate -s 0 $(OUT)
    cat $(SOURCES) > $(OUT)

clean: rm $(OUT)
```

In the commandline, you just have to remember to call `make`:

```
make && npm test
```

And voilà, the test cases know about the source code.

"Naked" functions, i.e. those not inside a namespace object, seem to confuse Jest. But luckily, in my case, everything in my source code is "namespaced".

Comment: You can also `"pretest": "make"`, then `npm test` will automatically build before running the tests.